# Return empty array instead of null

Tags: c#

I created `Settings` class which I use to edit my application by `.ini` file. My `Settings.ini` file looks like this:

```
[ACCOUNT]
login=xyz
password=xyz
locations=1,2,5,8
```

Now I am getting theese values like this:

```
class Settings {
    public static IniFile Config = new IniFile(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Settings.ini");
    public static string Login { get { return Config.Read("login", "ACCOUNT"); } set { Config.Write("login", "ACCOUNT"); } }
    public static string Password { get { return Config.Read("password", "ACCOUNT"); } set { Config.Write("password", "ACCOUNT"); } }
    public static int[] Locations { get { return Array.ConvertAll(Config.Read("locations", "ACCOUNT").Split(','), s => int.Parse(s)); } set { Config.Write("locations", "ACCOUNT"); } }
}
```

The problem is, when my `Settings.ini` file has empty locations:

```
locations=
```

My variable `Settings.Locations` return `null` instead of empty array. I've tried doing something like this:

```
public static int[] Locations 
{ 
    get { return new int[] {Array.ConvertAll(Config.Read("locations", "ACCOUNT").Split(','), s => int.Parse(s))}; } 
    set { Config.Write("locations", "ACCOUNT"); } 
}
```

But that is just not working. I cant convert int[] to int. Do you have any ideas how can I return empty array?

Comment: I dont get it, `Config.Read("locations", "ACCOUNT")` returns null if there are no locations? Because your `Locations` property never returns null because `Array.ConvertAll` never returns null. But if `Config.Read` returns null `string.Split` throws an exception.

Comment: You're right. Now I noticed I am getting `Format exception`

Comment: Instead of `Array.ConvertAll` you should use a loop and `int.TryParse` to try-parse every token. Then you can handle invalid input

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do it explicitly like this:

```
public static int[] Locations
{
    get
    {
        string locations = Config.Read("locations", "ACCOUNT");
        if (locations == null)
        {
            return new int[0];
        }
        return locations
                .Split(',')         // split the locations separated by a comma
                .Select(int.Parse)  // transform each string into the corresponding integer
                .ToArray();         // put the resulting sequence (IEnumerable<int>) into an array of integers
    }
    set
    {
        Config.Write("locations", "ACCOUNT");
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to change to: `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(works)) {` and it is working like a charm. Thanks :)

Comment: VS complaints about that now. It suggests `Array.Empty<int>();`.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you're jamming too much into one line so it makes it really hard to read let alone troubleshoot.  What you need is something like this:

```
public static int[] Locations 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        int[] values = Array.ConvertAll(Config.Read("locations", "ACCOUNT").Split(','), 
            s => int.Parse(s)) ?? new int[] { };
        return values; 
    } 
    set 
    { 
        Config.Write("locations", "ACCOUNT"); 
    } 
}
```

Notice I have added `?? new int[] { }` to the end of the first statement, which is called [the null coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).  It will return an empty array if the other array is null.

It's a matter of preference, but the reason I separated the getter into two lines is so I can debug and break before it returns to observe the return value.  You could also break on the last bracket instead and observe the return value in the Locals window.

Comment: Why declare values and not use it at all? Besides of the missing `;`

Comment: I was getting `Format exception` and I didint noticed it. Your code did not work aswell.